# the state of redux store is changed but mapStateToProps is not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I checked the `state` of `redux store` is changed, but `mapStateToProps` is not working.
Here is my file tree and code. What I want is that when I get the `data` from REST API by `axios` then I dispatches the `data` to `redux-store` and update the `state` of `redux-store`. After this, I finally get the `state` of `redux-store` as like `this.props.data`

```
index.js
MainPage.js
 - PageHeader.js
   - AlarmContentList.js
```

---

**MainPage.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux'

import store from '../../store'

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import axios from 'axios'


import * as AlarmContentActions from '../../store/modules/AlarmContent'

import PageHeader from './PageHeader'



class MainPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/main")
        .then(res => {
            
            this.setState({
                AnswerPostMultiList: res.data,
                
            })
            }
        )
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    state = {
        AnswerPostMultiList : [

        ],
    }
   
    render() {
        this.props._getInBox(this.state.AnswerPostMultiList)
        return(
            <>
                <PageHeader />   
            </>
        )
    }
}

MainPage.defaultProps = {
    
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    
    _getInBox: (inBoxList) => {
        dispatch(AlarmContentActions.inBox(inBoxList))
    }
  })

 

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage)
```

---

**PageHeader.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import './PageHeader.css'
import AlarmContentList from './AlarmContent/AlarmConentList'


class PageHeader extends Component {

    
    render() {
        return (
            <>
               <AlarmContentList />
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default PageHeader
```

---

**AlarmContentList.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'


class AlarmContentList extends Component {


    render() {
        console.log(this.props, 'this.props')
        return (
            <>
                <div>{this.props.inBox}<div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

AlarmContentList.defaultProps = {
    inBox: []
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
     inBox : state.inBox
    
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlarmContentList);
```

---

**index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux'

import store from '../../store'

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import MainPage from './MainPage'



ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <MainPage />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('main-page'))
```

---

**AlarmContent.js (redux-store)**

```
import {createAction, handleActions} from 'redux-actions'

//define action types
const INBOX = 'AlarmContent/INBOX';

//CREATE action
export const inBox = createAction(INBOX);


// SET initialState
const initialState = {
    inBox:[

    ]
}

// CREATE reducers
export default handleActions({
    [INBOX] : (state, action) => {
       return {
            ...state,
            inBox : action.payload
       } 
    },
}, initialState)
```

[image]
[image]

1. By checking `redux-dev-tool`, the procedure that I dispatch `data` and change `state` of `redux store` goes well, isn't it?
2. Even though `state` of `redux-store` is updated, why `props` from `redux-store` isn't changed??

[image]

(this result of image comes from `console.log(this.props, 'this.props')` at **AlarmContentList.js**)

Comment: What do u get if you do console.log(state.inBox) in mapStateToProps?

Comment: @Think-Twice you mean I should write like this `const mapStateToProps = (state) => (
    console.log(state.inBox),
    {
     inBox : state.inBox
    
})`?

Comment: @Think-Twice it shows `undefined`

Comment: Use `state.AlarmContent.inBox` instead `state.inBox` in `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: @AkhilP wow it works well!! really thanks! but why should I use `state.AlarmContent.inBox` instead of `state.inBox`? In my thought, `state` in `mapStateToProps` is same with `initialState` of `redux-store`, it is wrong?

Comment: Can add your `store.js` as well.? It depends on how you created your store.

Comment: @AkhilP it is related with using `combineReducers`?

Comment: Exactly. It'll attach the reducer's initialState to the key you've used in the combineReducers.

Comment: @AkhilP A-ha!! you save me, really really appreciate it!